# Dynamic asset subfolder path for Craft Commerce

Tags: assets, plugin-craftcommerce, upload, subfolder

I have a asset field where I would like to save the images in dynamic folders.
The upload folder should be parsed for the Dropdown field values in a Matrix field.

For a normal Dropdown field it works with

```
{{ object.dropdownFieldHandle }}
```

but for a Dropdown field in a Matrix field i can't get it working.

Any help is very appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave up my project to dynamically upload assets through matrix field dropdown values where the asset field is outside of the matrix field.
I actually just wanted to save assets in a logical structure.
I now save my craft commerce assets like this: product category/manufacturer/productionyear

```
{{ object.categoryFieldHandle.first.slug }}/{{ object.dropdownFieldHandle }}/{{ object.dropdownFieldHandle }}
```

Maybe this helps someone.

@Brad Bell thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an Asset field outside of Matrix and you want to set its "Upload Location" to be a dynamic value of Dropdown field inside of a separate Matrix field, something like this should work:

```
{{ object.matrixFieldHandle.type('matribBlockHandleTheFieldLivesIn').first().dropdownFieldHandle.value }}
```

Comment: Thank you Brad, i tried this and it didn't work. That's why i'm not sure if i asked my question properly. The asset field is not in the matrix field, just the dropdown field is in a matrix field. My intention was to dynamically upload the assets sorted by manufacturer.  And because there are a lot of different manufacturer for different product types i wanted to choose them per matrix field where each blocktype is a product type with a dropdown field for the manufacturers. Is that possible?

Comment: Ahh... I misunderstood, I think.  The Asset field is not in a Matrix field, just the dropdown. What's the name of the Matrix block the dropdown field lives in?  And is all of this in the context of a Commerce product?  And if so, does it have variants enabled?

Comment: Yes, the asset field is not in a Matrix field. The name of the matrix block where the dropdown field lives in is "manufacturerMountainbikes". The Matrix field "manufacturer" lives in the product field layout of a commerce product type. Yes i have variants enabled for color, framesize.

Comment: Updated the answer... hope that helps.